# как исправить недопустимое значение свойства в css??? Не пойму, что не так с этим классом. если с другими такими же все в порядке

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="layers__item layer-6" style="background-image: url(img/layer-6.png);"></div>
```

```css
.layer-6 {
    transform: rotateZ(380px);
}
```

выдает недопустимое значение возле transform: rotateZ(380px), как исправить?

Answer (score 5):

Поворот задаётся не в пикселях или сантиметрах, а в градусах или радианах (ну и ещё нескольких единицах измерения) - математика из начальной школы.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже ответили поворот задаётся не в пикселях(это вообще как?), а в градусах. Если хотите повернуть на 380 градусов, то достаточно повернуть на 20 градусов и получите тот же самый результат, т.к. полный круг 360 градусов(380-360=20).

Градусы в css обозначаются как `deg`. 20 градусов будут выглядеть соответственно так: `20deg`.

```css
.layer-6 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: rotateZ(20deg);
}
```

```html
    <div class="layers__item layer-6" style="background-image: url(https://placebear.com/g/200/200);"></div>
```

Comment: На 380 тоже можно.